# Android: Taking and saving picture, portrait mode/landscape mode

Tags: android, camera, rotation, landscape, portrait

When I am in portait mode with my android camera, the image seen is in landscape
So I wrote :

```
    Method rotateMethod;
    rotateMethod = android.hardware.Camera.class.getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", int.class);
    rotateMethod.invoke(camera, 90);
```

It works. Yet, when I save the image, the image his in landscape (width is bigger than height)
What could I do to collect the image (bytes[]) of what my camera saw ?

Comment: +1 for ur question. i m facing same issue. do u have solution?

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
Parameters p=camera.getParameters(); 
p.set("orientation", "portrait");    
camera.setParameters(p);
```

and start camera preview

Comment: Yeah I should have precised that I had already tried that and it did not work (I am in a lower APi probably)